# R create a multivariate time series matrix from normalised data.frame for hts()

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data.frame that has 3 columns:

```
 telar <- data.frame(
  class = c("A","B","A","B"),
  date = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-02-01")),
  number = c(10, 20, 11, 21)
)
```

The first one contains the class, the second one the date and the third one the date. I want to create a multivariate time series matrix that can be used by the hts function from the hts package. It should be a root node and the rest, leaves of the tree.

The code should look like this:

```
nodes <- list(length(unique(telar)))
## Here something to create the new time series matrix
my_hts <- hts(new_time_series_matrix, nodes)
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
new_time_series_matrix <- ts(
  select(
    dcast(telar, date ~ class), -date
  ),
  start=c(year(telar$date[1]), month(telar$date[1])), 
  frequency = 12
)
new_time_series_matrix
```

Output

```
          A  B
Jan 2019 10 20
Feb 2019 11 21
```